# How to limit permission of SDK in android?

Tags: android, sdk, permissions

I want to use a library in my project? But I do not want this lib to have permission to access files, database or download something from network in my app. How can I achieve my aim ?

The library is provide by others, I need use some function in it, but i do not want it has permission to hack my app. Maybe i need something like sandbox to run this lib, but I do not know how to achieve this?

Comment: permissions are app-related, not library related

Comment: Remove those permissions from menifest file...

Answer (score 0):

In your library projects, you can remove the permissions from manifest.
In terms of jar lib, there is no problem. Because jar libraries are going to use the app permissions only.

Comment: The library is provide by others, I need use some function in it, but i do not want it has permission to hack my app. Maybe i need a sandbox to run this lib, but I do not know how to achieve this?